# There is a period of radical transformation as political and economic uncertainty rise or rises?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I think it's pretty clear from the title. I don't know if I should be using the singular or plural form of 'to rise'. Thank you.

Comment: This sort of question has been asked here many times before. The consensus is that if you think 'political and economic uncertainty' comprises essentially a single multifaceted concern, it is better to indicate this using notional agreement (cf Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal). If not, use the more obvious agreement (Bacon and eggs are both to be found on the dairy aisle).

Answer (score 1):

It is simplest to look at *uncertainty rises* and say the singular noun takes a singular verb.

If you thought you are describing two uncertianties, then *political and economic uncertainties rise*.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in your example, if you insist on using the word "uncertainty" in the singular, one way to work around this is to replace "political and economic uncertainty" with "politico-economic uncertainty" and then you will be good to go with ***rises***.

> There is a period of radical transformation as *politico-economic
>   uncertainty* ***rises***.

ODO:

> **[politico-economic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/politico-economic)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> = politico-economical.
>
> **[politico-economical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/politico-economical)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Relating to or concerned with politics and economics; relating to
>   political economy.